# How do I make two arrows in css

Tags: html, css

I want to create an arrow using CSS only

Example you can see http://jsfiddle.net/b9Yfc/

On

```
<div id="arrow"><div id="arrow-inner"></div></div>
```

I want `arrow-inner` will be place into `arrow` and result should be like

[image]

How to achieve my goal?

Comment: You are using the same id twice in your example. Be careful not to do this in your real life version and use a class instead.

Comment: @RoToRa yeah.. will use class on real site :) thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play with the `position` properties

On `#arrow` add `position: relative;`

And on `#arrow-inner` add `position: absolute; top:-16px; left:-15px;`

And normaly it's works. See my http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/cAGWa/

Answer (score 4):

With css property `position`

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/felixsigl/hn9sc/

Comment: Thanks! @felixsigl If Stackoverflow allow me to accept two answers in one question will be nice.

Answer (score 2):

```
#arrow {
    position: relative;
    background: // the larger image
    width: // width of larger image
    height: // height of larger image
}
#arrow-inner {
    position: absolute;
    background: // the smaller image
    width: // the width of smaller image
    height: // the height of smaller image
    top: // the offset from the top of the larger image e.g. 2px
    left: // the offset from the left of the larger image e.g. 5px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following for your styling

```
#arrow {
    position: relative;
    background: url('url of the bigger image');

}
#arrow-inner {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('url of the smaller image');
    top: ;//dimmension in px for the vertical top displacement
    left: ;//dimmension in px for the vertical left displacement
    z-index:; dimmension in px for the z displacement though not neccessary
}
```